# How to create the system of linear equations from these constraints?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, projection

> Problem: Suppose a helicopter is currently at the position $(-1,0, 1)$ and
> moves in the direction $(1,2,2)$.
>
> a) Find a system of linear equations $Ax = b$, such that its solution set is the set of all points along the plane's tranjectory.
>
> b) Now suppose a second helicopter is at $(0,0,0)$ and travels along the same direction $(1,2,2)$. Let $T$ be the smallest subspace containing this trajectory. Compute a matrix $P \in R^{3×3}$
> such that, given a point $x \in R^3$
> , the
> point in T that is closest to x is equal to P x.

Here's what I have so far:

a) I'll first find a matrix A so that $$A\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
2 \\
2\\
\end{bmatrix} = 0$$ This will model what it'd be if we started at the origin instead. Just some basic algebra will give us
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & -2\\
2 & -1 & 0\\
-4 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
Now we need to shift by our starting point. $$A \left( \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
2 \\
2\\
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
0 \\
1\\
\end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}
-4 \\
-2 \\
5\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
So the answer should be $$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & -2\\
2 & -1 & 0\\
-4 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}x = \begin{bmatrix}
-4 \\
-2 \\
5\\
\end{bmatrix}$$ right?

Now for part b) I'm totally lost on how to go about doing this.

I think I need to find a projection matrix into subspace T, but I don't even know what T is.
Any ideas for how to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Since $T$ is the smallest subspace containing the trajectory from $u = (0,0,0)$ to $v = (1,2,2)$ then $T$ is of course the straight line spanned by the vector $v-u = v$. This is because this subspace has dimension $1$. The only subspace with a smaller dimension is the null subspace (dimension $0$) but this is not the case, because we already know that $T$ contains the vector $v$.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand. If I have a point x not in T, then is the the point closest to T from x  = (point in T - x)*x? I'm not really sure what you're trying to say...

Comment: you said that you didn't know what $T$ is, so I was trying to make that clear. After that, you were right about that what you need here is the projection matrix onto the subspace $T$. Does this answer your question?